# textView.setText does not update text but also gives no errors

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a `PopupWindow` that has a `TextView` in it. I am trying to change the text in this `TextView` dynamically but can't seem to get it to work. The code executes, but it does nothing and gives no errors, making it hard to understand what's happening (as there is nothing that shows up in the debug logs). It's important to note that this `TextView` is not in the same layout as the layout given to `setContentView` - and that `menu` is called when a button is pushed in the main layout. Does anybody have any idea why this could be happening?

Here is my code:

```
public void popupView(View view, int viewPointer){//viewPointer is R.id.popup_layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(viewPointer, null);

    // create the popup window
    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height,true);//add another parameter here (true) to make it so it goes away when clicked outside the menu itself
    popupWindow.setElevation(20);

    // show the popup window
    // which view you pass in doesn't matter
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    // dismiss the popup window when touched
    popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

and

```
public void menu(View view){
    textView.setText("this won't change the text but will execute with zero errors...");
    popupView(view, R.layout.popup_layout);
}
```

and in onCreate:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

View text_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);

textView = text_view.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
```

Comment: where menu() get called? post complete code

Comment: @chandmohd menu gets called when a button is pushed in another layout. I'll edit that into my question

Comment: Have you changed other elements about the TextView, to be sure you have the right object?

Comment: @Uuuuuumm yes, it is the right object (the name is something much more distinct that textView in my actual code, I just changed it so it's easier for a reader to understand here on SO)

Comment: You need to find that `TextView` in the `View popupView` you inflate in `popupView()`. The `View text_view` you inflate in `onCreate()` is a completely separate instance of that layout that is not on-screen anywhere.

Comment: @MikeM. this worked! If you post this as an answer I'll accept it